# Can't add more fields to Java JsonNode after .set("field name", JsonNode)

Tags: java, json, playframework

I'm writing tests for a Java Play web application using Play.test and org.junit. Some tests call our API's via http requests. I create a JsonNode whenever I need to include a Request Body with my requests.

One such request requires me to include an array.

Code:

```
JsonNode arr = Json.newArray()
                    .add("Element 1")
                    .add("Element 2")
                    .add("Element 3");
            sendNode =
                    Json.newObject()
                        .put("foo_id", "stringy string")
                        .put("name", "New foo")
                        .set("an_array", arr);
```

I have no issue adding this array. The above code works as is; However, if I add a line:

```
... //Same as above
sendNode = 
Json.newObject()
.put("foo_id", "stringy string")
.put("name", "New foo")
.set("an_array", arr)
.put("another_field", "value")
```

Suddenly there is an error. I can't add any more fields to the object.

I am looking for a way to achieve this desired Json Object (HTTP Request Body):

```
{
  foo_id: "123abc",
  name: "thisthing",
  an_array: ["element1", "element2", "element3"],
  another_field: "fieldvalue"
}
```

Comment: Which error do you get? I am assuming an exception - could you post the stack trace?

Comment: Error:(2073, 25) java: cannot find symbol

  symbol:   method put(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  location: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode

Answer (score 0):

Ho boy, do I feel silly. I simply needed to use the .putPOJO(String, Object) method!

I am posting the solution here for anyone else who is silly like myself:

```
JsonNode arr = Json.newArray()
        .add("Element 1")
        .add("Element 2")
        .add("Element 3");
JsonNode sendNode = Json.newObject()
        .put("foo_id", "idString")
        .put("name", "foo's name")
        .putPOJO("array_field", arr)
        .put("another_field", "string value");
```

The .putPOJO() method, unlike the set() method, returns the node being created, to allow the chaining required to continue adding to the node.